# Problem Displaying User Action Logs in the updated Joomla 3.9. *

Tags: user, logs

I don't remember which version I started with Joomla. However, I have been using it for about 5-6 years. The latest version is 3.9.23.

Due to a problem we are experiencing, I need information on the dates when a user logs in and out. I hadn't checked the **User Actions Logs** section before, as I never needed this information. However, although I have activated the feature now, when I enter the User Actions Logs section, no data comes out. I have been doing research on this for about a week. Finally, I learned that this feature does not work for users who upgrade to **3.9.0** version. The related article url is below.

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:User_Action_Logs

As a result, a very good explanation was made, but I could not solve the problem because I am a standard user who does not know how the system works. When I re-install by deleting **Joomla 3.9.23** I see the transaction log in the **User Action Logs** section. But when I do this, I cannot use the CiviCRM plugin with its data.

Can you tell me what I need to do to use **User Actions Logs**? For example, in the solution I sent in the URL, where should the codes given in the "Component Installation Script" steps be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatih,

Welcome to Joomla Stack Exchange.

You might now have looked at that JDOC more than I have, so feel free to provide feedback (here or PM me) as to what didn't make sense so it can be rewritten, but at the moment I'll be flagging that as a doc to come back to review in the next batch I work on.

When you go to **Users > Users Actions Log** in the Administrator area of the site, if the various settings to record different actions are turned on, you'll see action logs accumulating as you do things ranging from logging in and out, to making various system changes. If that's blank, then you most likely have functionality turned off for recording various events.

[image]

If you then click on **Options** in the top right of the screen, you're then shown a list of Events to Log from the Joomla Action logs plugin.

[image]

With **Users** checked in the options list, you should then at least be then recording the log in and logged out information you are after.

If you're not seeing the data being logged, then the **Action Log - Joomla** plugin may be disabled, preventing logging from occurring on these core items.

To check if that plugin is disabled, go to **Extensions > Plugins**, then use Search Tools to filter for **actionlog** plugins. Enable it, then log out and log back in before checking **Users > User Actions Log** to see whether your logging off and back on are then recorded in the logs.

[image]

In addition to the core there's other plugins some components will have installed, and you can see those and enable/disable them by filtering for **actionlog** plugins via **Extensions > Plugins**, then enabling / disabling them as required.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your support and this detailed explanation. The "User Transactions Log" option in the plug-in management was enabled, but the "System - User Transactions Log" was inactive. My problem was solved by activating this option. Thank you again. "+1" "thanks"